# upLaTeX & DVI output - "font file over" error

Tags: fonts, dvi, uplatex

I use the upLaTeX (from TeXLive) and DVI output. The error `font file over: C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\vf\uptex\jis\upjisr-h` is appears.

I've tried to set the `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist` to full control, however, nothing changed.

[image: DVI output error message]

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{ujarticle}
\begin{document}
upLaTeX検査。今日は！
\end{document}
```

however, your DVI oputput already setted and will display everything, I can suppose.

Maybe I need to set to full control anythig else?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? Does the file upjisr-h.vf exist?

Comment: Yes, I've checked this file.

Comment: What's the exact entire output of the upLaTeX run?

Comment: I made the screenshot of error window. Please, look the question field. If to push `OK`, the DVI output app will close.

Comment: Strange. Does another DVI viewer work? Or converting the DVI to a PDF?

Comment: DVI2PDF is O'K, but it's not comfortable to use DVI2PDF after each upLaTeX compile, it't it? YAP (from portable MiKTeX) error message is `MiKTeX Problem Report Message: Not all fonts could be loaded.` However, YAP linked with MiKTeX portable, not with TeXLive.

Comment: I'm not sure the DVI can be previewed; if I run `dvipdfmx`, then I can preview correctly the result.

Answer (score 2):

There is no DVI viewer for files produced by upTeX that I know of. If I run `dvitype` on the DVI file, I get errors regarding the Japanese character. However, running `updvitype` presents no error.

I guess that the only feasible alternative is converting to PDF, which can be done by a script available in TeX Live (and perhaps also in MiKTeX):

```
ptex2pdf -u -l <filename>
```

where `-u` means “use upTeX” and `-l` means “use the LaTeX format”.

Answer (score 1):

with an up-to-date TeXLive 2013 and the upcoming TeXLive 2014 I used

```
uplatex <file>
dvipdfmx <file.dvi>
```

I get only a warning from the last step:

> ** WARNING ** CMap has higher supplement number than CIDFont: Ryumin-Light
>   ** WARNING ** Some chracters may not be displayed or printed.

but the output seems to be ok:

[image]

If you get an error try to reinstall the `uplatex` package with the TeXLive manager.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but the following produces Japanese (or at least what looks like Japanese to me) using `xelatex` and produces a PDF (on Mac OS X at least):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra} %xltxtra = fontspec, xunicode, etc.
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\linespread{1.05}
\begin{document}

日本語で書くためにはIPA明朝を使っていいです。しかし、時々英語などで書
く機会があります。その時、

を入力したら、英語のためのフォントで書ける。

たとえば、

に関しては次の を参照してください：
\end{document}
```

Perhaps that would work for you? XeLaTeX is designed from the ground up to support UTF-8 and system fonts.

Comment: Thanks you, I'm already use the XelaTeX. I think that upLaTeX compiles more faster than XeLaTeX (it's significant for big projects with a lot of pages, pictures etc.).